# Timestamp is ruining my graph in ggplot2, How can I fix this?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, timestamp

I have a data set called `X1234` and I have three columns (num, timestamp, Levels of concentration), here is a sample of what my data looks like:

```
num | timestamp      | Levels of Concentration
1   | 4/2/2019 10:45 | 60.80
2   | 4/2/2019 11:00 | 60.08
3   | 4/2/2019 11:15 | 60.08
4   | 4/2/2019 11:30 | 60.26
5   | 4/2/2019 11:45 | 60.26
6   | 4/2/2019 12:00 | 60.44
7   | 4/2/2019 12:15 | 60.44
8   | 4/2/2019 12:30 | 60.44
9   | 4/2/2019 12:45 | 60:62
10  | 4/2/2019 13:00 | 60.62
```

When I use [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot) to plot a graph of the area (the x-axis = `num`, y-axis = `Levels of Concentration`) I get a good graph, however, I want to do this with a `timestamp`. Here is the picture of what I would like my graph to look like and the code I used for it was :

```
ggplot(X1234, aes(x = X1234$num, y=X1234$`Levels of Concentration`)) + geom_area()
```

Ideal Graph
[image: Ideal graph]

However I need to use the `timestamp` as the x-axis, but when I do so my graph changes completely and I don't understand why. Here is the code I used for the second graph (x = `timestamp`, y = `Levels of Concentration`)

```
X1234$timestamp_local <- as.Date (X1234$timestamp_local, '%m/%d ')
ggplot(data = X1234, aes (x= X1234$timestamp_local, y = X1234$`Levels of Concentration`)) +  geom_area()
```

My actual graph using the timestamp
[image: My actual graph using the timestamp]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be very helpful if you could provide a reprex: https://reprex.tidyverse.org/

Comment: Please include data as text using `dput(X1234)` rather than an image. This will help others help you. And you should not use $ in the `aes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `num` is a number which is plotted an a continuous scale, while `timestamp` is of type character which results in a discrete scale.

For plotting `timestamp` on a continuous scale it needs to be coerced to the datetime class `POSIXct` properly, e.g., by using `lubridate::mdy_hm()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
ggplot(X1234) +
  aes(x = mdy_hm(timestamp), y = `Levels of Concentration`) +
  geom_area()
```

[image]

#### Data

```
X1234 <- readr::read_delim("
num | timestamp      | Levels of Concentration
1   | 4/2/2019 10:45 | 60.80
2   | 4/2/2019 11:00 | 60.08
3   | 4/2/2019 11:15 | 60.08
4   | 4/2/2019 11:30 | 60.26
5   | 4/2/2019 11:45 | 60.26
6   | 4/2/2019 12:00 | 60.44
7   | 4/2/2019 12:15 | 60.44
8   | 4/2/2019 12:30 | 60.44
9   | 4/2/2019 12:45 | 60.62
10  | 4/2/2019 13:00 | 60.62", delim = "|", trim_ws = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you @Uwe, I was able to use lubridate on my full dataset. And that allowed my timestamp to change to a continuous scale.